# Wordpress navigation using wp_dropdown_pages without submit button

Tags: wordpress

I'm tyring to make a simple drop down navigation GUI using wp_dropdown_pages() something along the lines of this non functioning code;

```
   <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
   <?php wp_dropdown_pages(array('echo' => '1')); ?>
   <onchange='return this.form.submit()'>
   </form>
```

I know its somethinng to do with the echo, I think,. PS Dont want to use a submit button. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have worked out an what was going on from a wordpress [post]:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/is-the-new-dropdown_categories-working?replies=13#post-657759

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("cat");
    function onCatChange()
    {
        if ( dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value > 0 )
        {
            location.href = "<?php echo get_option('home');
            ?>/?cat="+dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
        }
    }
    dropdown.onchange = onCatChange;
    --></script>
```